# Using the date from the next row as the end date of the current row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table laid out as follows:

```
ID | FOCUS      | DATE
----------------------------
 1 | equipment  | 2018-01-01
 2 | uniform    | 2018-02-14
 3 | attendance | 2018-04-03
```

The rows are added as new focuses are introduced.

I want to be able to get the start date and end date for a particular focus, assuming it ends as the next one starts. Procuding a view such as:

```
ID | FOCUS      | STARTDATE  | ENDDATE
--------------------------------------
 1 | equipment  | 2018-01-01 | 2018-02-14
 2 | uniform    | 2018-02-14 | 2018-04-03
 3 | attendance | 2018-04-03 | NULL
```

The database I'm using has no LEAD or LAG functions, so I need a way to do it in pure SQL. All solutions I've found so far use LEAD and LAG. Any ideas?

Comment: What database *are* you using that doesn't support window functions? Old release of MySQL or Sqlite?

Comment: I'm using an old mySQL version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the result you want by `LEFT JOIN`ing the table to itself, on the right table's date being the minimum date value greater than the left table's date. This query will work regardless of `ID` values being consecutive:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.FOCUS, t1.DATE AS STARTDATE, t2.DATE AS ENDDATE
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.DATE = (SELECT MIN(DATE)
                                  FROM table1 t3
                                  WHERE t3.DATE > t1.DATE)
```

Output:

```
ID  FOCUS       STARTDATE   ENDDATE
1   equipment   2018-01-01  2018-02-14
2   uniform     2018-02-14  2018-04-03
3   attendance  2018-04-03  null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7W93g4ypSmGqPKfuvBtgL/0)

If it's possible that two events might end on the same day, you can modify the query like the following, which will work as long as `ID` values increase as `DATE` values increase.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.FOCUS, t1.DATE AS STARTDATE, t2.DATE AS ENDDATE
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.DATE = (SELECT MIN(DATE)
                                  FROM table1 t3
                                  WHERE t3.DATE >= t1.DATE AND t3.ID > t1.ID)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7W93g4ypSmGqPKfuvBtgL/1)

Comment: @VladimirBaranov good point. OP doesn't mention that as an option but always good to cover all bases. I've edited my answer...

Comment: @MattGray . . . Also correct, this is more complicated than necessary.  It is doing an unnecessary `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
select t.id, t.focus, t.date as startdate, t2.date as enddate 
from 
   (select focus, date, row_number() over (order by date asc)  as rn 
    from tableA) t
left join 
   (select focus, date, row_number() over (order by date asc) as rn from tableA) t2
       on t2.rn + 1 = t.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

Without LEAD and LAG, you can write it with a subquery that would fetch a date from an ID+1 row, like this:

```
SELECT qry.id
     , qry.focus
     , qry.date as startdate
     , (select sbq.date from your_table sbq where sbq.id = (qry.id + 1)) as enddate
  FROM your_table qry
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select min(t2.date)
        from t t2
        where t2.date > t.date
       ) as enddate
from t;
```

If you have dates that are the same, you can use `id` to distinguish the values.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.date
        from t t2
        where t2.date > t.date or
              (t2.date = t.date and t2.id > t.id)
        order by t2.date asc, t2.id asc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as enddate
from t;
```

Note:  You don't specify the database you are using.  `fetch first` is standard SQL; some databases use `limit`, others use `select top`.